# What is the electric field graph of a uniformly charged square sheet (not infinite) along its central axis?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

Question:
A square of side length a with uniformly distributed positive charge lies on the yz-plane with its center at the origin. What is the graph of the electric field along the x-axis?

[image: Diagram]

Below is the correct graph for the question.

[image: The correct graph]

According to my textbook, this is the correct graph for electric field. However, I am a little bit unsure about the shape. The graph suggests that the strength of electric field increases within a range and then decreases. However, I cannot come up with a reason for this increase by the electric field formula. What is the reason behind this increase?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> However, I cannot come up with a reason for this increase by the electric field formula. What is the reason behind this increase?

If you had an *infinite* sheet of charge, you would have a *constant* electric field value of
$$
E_x = +\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}
$$
along the positive x axis, and
$$
E_x = -\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}
$$
along the negative x axis.

For the *infinite* sheet, the field is constant except when it switches discontinuously from $
-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}
$
to
$
+\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}
$
as you cross the sheet.

---

For a **finite** sheet the field should still cross zero at the x origin, but the field is continuous. This means the field is zero at $x=0$ and rises up to about $+\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ over a "short" distance as you move from $x=0$ to some positive $x$ value. And similarly as you move from $x=0$ to some small negative $x$ value the field should shoot down to $-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$.

---

The decrease back down to zero as you move to large positive or large negative values is also expected since as you get far enough away the finite sheet just looks like a point charge at the origin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it! Just for a clarification, why can't the sheet be considered as the surface of a conductor, so the electric field at the surface will be charge density/elipson zero?

Comment: @ZZZ You specified in the problem statement: "uniformly charged square sheet." In such a case the field is given as I stated. If it is literally a "square sheet" it has no thickness and can not be a physical conductor. If on the other hand you have a thin lamina with a square cross section, then it certainly could be a conductor, but the problem would be different. In that case, if you specified that the same amount of charge is on the thin conductor, the field would look similar to the case discussed here.